# Convert string to datetime to year and month SQL

Tags: sql, string, datetime

How do i get the year(2009) and month(12) from the string datetime, following give me correct full date but wrong year (1905-07-03 00:00:00.000) and month (1900-01-13 00:00:00.000). I have tried changing YYYY to year and MM to month.

```
Declare @date dateTime;
Declare @CurrentYear datetime;
Declare @CurrentMonth datetime;
Select @date = CONVERT ( datetime , '20091231' ,112 );
Select @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YYYY,@date);
--Select @CurrentYear = YEAR(@Date);  <---- still wrong year
Select @CurrentMONTH = DATEPART(MM,@date);
--Select @CurrentMonth = MONTH(@date);   <---- still wrong year
select @date as fulldate, @CurrentYear as [year], @CurrentMonth as [Month];
```

None of the SO suggestions has worked so far.

regards
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `DATEPART`, use `YEAR (YY or YYYY)` or `MONTH (M or MM)` for your year and month parts:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = CAST('20091231' as DATETIME)   -- ISO-8601 format always works

SELECT 
    DATEPART(YEAR, @date),    -- gives 2009
    DATEPART(YYYY, @date),    -- gives 2009
    DATEPART(MONTH, @date),   -- gives 12
    DATEPART(MM, @date)       -- gives 12
```

Does that help at all??

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
 declare @d datetime
 select @d = '20091231'

 select YEAR(@d),MONTH(@d),  year(getdate()) as CurrentYear
```

Comment: sort of.. assignment to @CurrentYear and @CurrentMonth was causing the dates to go wrong, when i did "select DATEPART(YYYY,@date) as [year],DATEPART(MM,@date) as [Month]" it worked